# Shared preference set in fragment, access in main activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, sharedpreferences

I have set a sharedpreference value in a fragment. But when I try to access that value in main activity, I always get default value ;( Please tell me why...

In fragment:

```
    reader= this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref",0); // this is in onCreate

            //this part within a onClick
    editor = reader.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Preferences.passwordOn, true); 
    editor.putString(Preferences.password, editTextPassword.getText().toString()); 
    editor.commit();
```

In main activity:

```
    boolean passwordOn = reader.getBoolean(Preferences.passwordOn, false);
    if(passwordOn)
    {
        Intent loginIntent=new Intent("com.sdg.etspandroidtracker.LOGIN");
        startActivity(loginIntent);
    }
```

UPDATE: my code is too messy and huge. :( So i'll tell what happens there.

In main activity, first I check if a password is set for the application. If so, I display the login screen and end main activity as given above in the second code part. Else, I just keep main activity.

In settings, I have a switch to on/off password. When I on the switch, a fragment is displayed where you can enter new password and password confirmation. If all details are correct, password and status of password(the information if a password is set) is saved in the shared preference. This code is the first code part I have given above.

I can successfully run the app, on the password and and set it. But when I run the application again, login screen is not displayed. I debugged and found out that this is because sharedpreference is empty and gives the default value "false" even though I set the password last time I run the app. Seems I cant access the sharedpreference I set in fragment, in the main activity? :\

Answer (score 1):

If you want to communicate from an activity to a fragment, you can use [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/) and send a message that can be intercepted.
But if your code is messy it may be not a good idea...

Comment: EventBus may be a right choice, but I prefer to write an interface inside the fragment and make the attached activity implement the interface

Answer (score 0):

You should look **when** you call your **if-block** in `MainActivity`. Because if you call your **if-block** **before** setting new values in your `fragment`, you will get the old ones. Can you provide more code, like when do you call your **if-block** and what does the fragment actually do, or when it is created?

Comment: I got the answer :S a very silly mistake. I have used two different keys to get shared preference in the two different places.

Comment: Ok :) You should use some type of encryption at least http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29 , MODE_PRIVATE if you look here, you can also find more information about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck at the same problem, but the solution is not as trivial. I was using `Butterknife` to bind the resource value (in this case the key as a string).

When invoked with shared preference using the string in different activity it was always using the default value. Directly using the string makes it work.